# Заполнить 3-мерный массив случайными числами от 0 до 1

Tags: java

Пытаюсь заполнить трёхмерный массив случайными числами от 0 до 1:

```
//объект класса Random
Random random = new Random();
//создаём трёхмерный массив(3 столбца, 3 ряда)
int[][][] array = new int[3][3][3];
//заполняем его случайными значениями
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < array[i].length; j++ ){
        for(int k = 0; k < array[j].length; k++) {
            array[i][j][k] = random.nextInt(1);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

В конце программа должна вывести массив в виде строки, но выводит это:

> [[[I@74a14482, [[I@1540e19d, [[I@677327b6]

Как исправить?

Comment: поставить `System.out.print` в тело цикла

Answer (score 4):

Этот вывод вполне логичен.

Лучше, конечно, написать для этого отдельный метод, и делать это в цикле.

Или использовать готовые/другие способы из других ответов. Ниже объясняю, в чём проблема.

Метод `Arrays.toString` обходит массив не рекурсивно, он пробежался в цикле по самому верхнему массиву и для каждого его элемента вызвал `String.valueOf(a[i])`, а каждый элемент - это двумерный массив. Ведь трехмерный массив это массив двумерных массивов, то есть массив массивов одномерных массивов :) А ошибки не было потому, что трехмерный массив это тоже одномерный массив, только его элементы тоже массивы.

Comment: стоит указать, что траблы именно из-за того, что метод Arrays.toString принимает на входе одномерный массив.

Comment: @tilin трёхмерный массив это тоже одномерный массив, только вот его элементы это двухмерные массивы, верно ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Вам поможет [Arrays.deepToString(array)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> array[i][j][k] = random.nextInt(1);
> ```

Этот код заполнит ваш массив только 0, т.к. метод `nextInt` на вход принимает границу **невключительно**. В вашем случае нужно передать 2 - тогда в массиве будут 0 и 1.

Как писали ранее для вывода массива вы можете:
1. Обойти массив таким же способом как вы его заполняли (либо выводить значение сразу после заполнения

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < array[i].length; j++ ){
        for(int k = 0; k < array[j].length; k++) {
            array[i][j][k] = random.nextInt(2);
            System.out.print(array[i][j][k] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

> 1 1 1
>   1 1 1
>   1 0 0
>
> 0 1 0
>   1 1 0
>   0 1 1
>
> 0 1 0
>   0 0 1
>   0 1 1

2.Использовать `Arrays.deepToString(array)`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

> [[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]], [[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]], [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]]

3.Извращаться с помощью stream-ов :) (делать этого, конечно, не стоит)

```
Arrays.stream(array)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .map(Arrays::stream)
        .map(IntStream::boxed)
        .map(s -> s.map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

> 1 1 1
>   1 1 1
>   1 0 0
>   0 1 0
>   1 1 0
>   0 1 1
>   0 1 0
>   0 0 1
>   0 1 1